How to maximize Playerpower while minimizing Crest expenses World of Warcraft
I did not finish my math degree and never took Optimization so Im out of practice and unfamiliar with the methodology and I would be interested in formulating this WoW Problem in abstract language, finding a solution to it, and generalizing it, its quite interesting.
In Wow you wear certain equipment, like weapon or rings (fixed number of equipment slots) and those items have itemlevel and stats, aswell as can have special effects that make them/you stronger. Your Playerpower depends on those stats and effects. The Effect the stats and items have can also depend on the other items/on the combination of all of them.
You can upgrade the itemlevel of the Items by spending a currency named Crest. Increasing the itemlevel will increase the stats and passive effects, but not change them. There are different Types of Crests and which one and how many to use depends on the Start and End Itemlevel of the upgrade. The items existing are limited.
You acquire a fixed number of crests when doing dungeons. You can also get new items from dungeons. Since your Crests are a limited ressource, you do not want to spend them on an Item that you will later replace. The itemlevel and type of Crest you get depends on the dungeon level, the items which are possible to get depend on the dungeon type.
You could theoretically influence the order in which you get items by doing specific dungeons, but not the probability of getting them. In the real game if you upgrade a slot once, you dont have to spend more crests to get to the same itemlevel with a new item again, you unlock it. But I would also be interested in the general cases, of random dungeons and upgrades without "warranty". The amount of crest you can acquire overall or in a certain amount of time (a week) can be limited or unlimited. The amount of crests you can hold at once can be limited or unlimited.
The question is now simply, what should I upgrade and when i.e. how do I maximize playerpower at any given time while minimizing crest losses or avoiding them alltogether (longterm vs shortterm).
I came up with there being no perfect solution, because you cannot know when you will get the next item, so you cannot know if hoarding the Crests is the right thing. Also the optimal solution in words would probably be "Do the upgrades that will make you most powerful in the most number of cases".
What math theory could you apply to this, what is the solution and how to generalize it? How would special cases look like for example the strength of an item only depending on the item itself and not other gear pieces?

The problem you are describing sounds very complicated. Maybe a simpler version is the following: given a fixed number of crests and a certain set of equipment, what is the maximum power you can get now? This is basically a resource allocation problem, whihc can be solved with dynamic programming. See for example https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/course_builder/1415/math3220/L8.pdf

You can formulate this process as a Markov Decision Process. In such a process, you have a state space $S$, an action space $A$, a reward function $R:S\times S\times A\to\mathbb{R}$ and a collection of transition probabilities $P:S\times A\to \Delta(S)$, where $\Delta(S)$ is the probability simplex of $S$ (the set of probability distributions on $S$).
This sounds abstract but is actually very straightforward. You start with an initial state $S_0$. Say this state is your current equipment, together with the crests that you hold. The action space $A$ is the set of possible gear upgrades, including the choice not to upgrade anything. Choose an action $a_0$. Then you will receive a reward $R(s_0,a_0)$, which is the increment in your character's power (by some metric you can decide on). Then you transition to the next state, $S_1$. We could imagine that, between $S_0$ and $S_1$, one piece of content was completed, so with some probability, your equipment has changed, and your available number of crests has changed. Now it's as if we're back at the start. The process reaches its terminal state when there are no more available upgrades.
Given a Markov Decision Process, a policy $\pi$ is a mapping $\pi:S\to A$, i.e. it assigns an action to each state. The field of reinforcement learning is concerned with finding the optimal policy $\pi^*$, which maximises the expected (discounted) sum of rewards $\mathbb{E}[\sum_{t=0}^T\gamma^t R(s_t,s_{t+1},a_t)]$. Here, $0<\gamma\leq 1$ is the discounting factor, which specifies the extent to which you prefer to receive short term rewards over long term rewards.
There are algorithms which can find the optimal policy, but I have no idea how tractable this particular problem is, because I have no idea what the actual size of $S$ is, but I think it is huge, making the problem difficult. In any case you are not going to find a nice closed-form solution.
If you wanted to solve this problem using reinforcement learning, you would have to define a suitable reward function $R$, and create an environment in which to simulate the process. Maybe start out by keeping $S$ small by deliberately restricting the potential new equipment that can be acquired.
